# Recreating a CakePHP 1.2 project in order to upgrade

Tags: php, nginx, cakephp, vagrant, cakephp-1.3

I've got a CakePHP 1.2-based web site (I know.. *too* ancient) that I need to upgrade only to whatever is the oldest Cake to support PHP 7.1 (I think roughly Cake 2.8, from what I've seen so far), because my host is upgrading PHP to 7.1 across the board. This site only needs to live maybe 1 more year before we totally replace it, but we don't have time to do that before the host upgrades PHP at end of year.

I am trying to get the web site *as-is* running in a vagrant VM, so I can go through the upgrade steps there, carefully, and understand exactly what I need to do. My problem now is that I can't get the site to display. More concretely, when I try to load the site with nginx in vagrant, I get **nothing but a blank screen** with a few PHP warnings (strict standards to the effect of `Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically`), but nothing obviously *broken*. There's basically nothing in the PHP log, and nothing in the Nginx log. Again, this is the site as currently running (successfully) in production, which means my vagrant PHP is 5.6.38 (the actual production PHP is 5.6.25). Running with php-fpm.

Cake's own logs are only reporting the following, which arises inside a controller method `function disableCache()`, which is trying to insert headers to prevent the browser from caching the request:

```
2018-10-22 15:18:57 Warning: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/share/nginx/html/www.mydomain.com/cake/libs/object.php:63) in [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 844]
```

I have inserted an early return in that method just to stop these warnings.

In PHP, I've got these settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/php_errors.log');
```

In Cake 1.2's `app/config/core.php`, I've got:

```
Configure::write('debug', 3);
```

Database is local MySQL in vagrant, with settings in `app/config/database.yml`.

Can someone suggest where I should go next in debugging this?

Comment: Try executing the code with `php -l` from the command line. A white screen usually means a 500 server error. Might be from a simple syntax error somewhere in your code that's preventing the interpreter from getting to your additional logging configuration.

Comment: Thanks... `php -l` on the main index.php for the site gives `No syntax errors detected in index.php`.

Comment: You might need to pass in the path that you want to access. Not sure how to do that on the command line with Symfony, you can probably iterate over files specific to your app (likely any errors aren't in the framework code).

Comment: You say nothing in the PHP or Nginx log; what about the Cake logs? Maybe include those "nothing obviously broken" warnings in your question? Perhaps something is subtly broken. :-)

Comment: @GregSchmidt thanks.. my bad... the pace where Cake logs were supposed to go had been empty thru most of this process, but now there's something there :) Will update the question.

Comment: From personal experience, all of the "non-static method" warnings can be made to go away by editing the Cake core files in question and making those specific functions static. (Normally, editing core files is a no-no, because you lose your edits when you update, but that's obviously not an issue here.) By doing that, you may eliminate all of the early output that's causing the "Cannot modify header information" warning, and once that's gone, maybe more useful information will start to reveal itself.

Comment: By the way, have you given thought to using a different host for this (once you get it working again with PHP 5.6) for the next year, instead of upgrading your app to Cake 2.8? Depending on the size of it, it may well be more work than it's worth to do such an upgrade. Especially if it's going to be fully obsoleted soonish. Of course, details of your situation may render this option infeasible.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thx for all the ideas... yes, moving the site to another host could be an option, altho we're a university org and using the university IT services is convenient in various ways. But will keep that in mind. For now I haven't reached the limit of patience with the upgrade yet :)

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, `PHP 7.1` and `CakePHP 1.2` can work together. You simply need to upgrade your source code to make it compatible with `PHP 7.1` but you can continue to have your system in `CakePHP 1.2` without having to upgrade `CakePHP`. Of course, if you can use a newer or the latest version of `CakePHP` that would be perfect but think of it as a separate project and not something you must do now only because your host is upgrading PHP to 7.1 across the board.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your Cake project upgraded to `1.3.21` (the last `1.x` release), you  may be able to use this: https://github.com/littleant/cakephp-1.3.21 instead of upgrading to Cake 2.x. Might buy you a little time!